# Reuse angular2 component from child module on root level route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following route structure

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: SignInComponent },
 {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: BaseComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        { path: '', component: DashboardPageComponent },
        {
          path: 'greenscreens', loadChildren: './+child/child.module#ChildModule'
        }
      ]
   },
   { path: 'greenscreen/:id', component:  ViewChildComponent },
   { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent }
];
```

I want to access a component from the ChildModule on the root level route  `'greenscreen/:id'`. Can I accomplish this without using a Shared Module ?

Comment: You can't import part of a module I believe. Either split it out to its own module or import the whole `ChildModule`.

Comment: I tried importing the child module and then using it but it overwrites the routes on the parent

Comment: Yes. It's because your `ChildModule`'s routing was defined to served lazy-loaded module. If you decide to integrate `ChildModule` into app module, you'd need to rewrite routing strategy for that bit.